# How to type left or right tag on a hp spectre 13.3

Tags: keyboard

So I bought a HP Spectre (HP Spectre 13-v002no (ENERGY STAR)) yesterday and as I was about to start writing some HTML markup, I realized the left and right tag key was not available between the left shift and z-key. Instead it was located on the right side of the alt gr-key. However, it only seems to function as a right ctrl-key, even though the physical key displays left and right tag, backslash and pipe. 
I used SharpKeys and the left tag is assigned to 00_33 but I'm not sure what that means or how to use that information. I've tried all the normal combinations, like shift+key, alt+key, altgr+key, fn+key and so on, but no luck.
[Here's a photo of the key in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAk6k.jpg)

So my question is simply, how do I access these symbols? Thankful for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed by updating the BIOS (F26)

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Can you provide more information, such as a quote from the BIOS update's release notes?